# Diffeomorphism $\varphi:(0,1)^2\rightarrow U$. $U$ is a parallelogram

Tags: diffeomorphism

> Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be a open parallelogram with vertices $(2,3), (6,4), (8,6), (4,5)$. Find a diffeomorphism $\varphi:(0,1)\times (0,1)\rightarrow U$.

How can I find such an Diffeomorphism? I tried to do it with polar coordinates but I think it is wrong.

Comment: What did you try, exactly? Please share in an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look at the coefficients in a linear combination of the vectors spanning the parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks. I got $\varphi(x,y)=(4,1)^Tx+(2,2)^Ty+(2,3)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Moritz, yep. (: